# dynamic generation of system of equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, ode

I am new to Mathematica and am trying to figure out how to dynamically generate a system of ODEs.  For example I have a system of 100 equations where every 10 are essentially the same but with slightly different parameters that can be read from a vector (of length 10).  I would like to write the 10 equations out, then loop over some iterator to generate all 100 equations.  Is there a standard way to do this?

For example, here is a system of 30 equations (for i in 1:10):

```
 dX_i/dt = -\beta*X_i*Y_i + \delta_{i-1}*X_{i-1} - \delta_i*X_{i}
 dY_i/dt = \beta*X_i*Y_i - \gamma_i*Y_i + \delta_{i-1}*Y_{i-1} - \delta_i*Y_{i} 
 dZ_i/dt = \gamma_i*Y_i + \delta_{i-1}*Z_{i-1} - \delta_i*Z_{i}
```

It seems redundant to copy paste new equations if I increase the i to say, 100 (i.e. giving us three hundred ODEs).

Comment: Do you have a _coupled_ system of 100 ODEs, or 10 sets of 10 ODEs? ... Or anything else?

Comment: So it is a coupled system of 100 ODEs but they can be divided into sets of 10.  To give you some more details, they represent 10 age classes in a 10 compartment model. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nope, I don't understand. How many of them are coupled?

Comment: Are you using Mathematica syntax in your example? Try to do a simple DSolve first ...

Comment: No, I was writing in pseduo-latex code in the above example.  I do realize I need to write in Mathmatica syntax when using Mathematica though.

Comment: Post mathematica code here ... much easier for us ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it goes, but probably Mathematica is not going to be able to solve it (depending on your coefficients)

```
Table[(delta[i] = i; gamma[i] = -i), {i, 0, 10}];
b = 1;
DSolve[Flatten@Table[{
    x[i]'[t] == -b x[i][t] y[i][t] + delta[i - 1] x[i - 1][t] - delta[i] x[i][t],
    y[i]'[t] == -b x[i][t] y[i][t] - gamma[i] y[i][t] + delta[i - 1] y[i - 1][t] - delta[i] y[i][t],
    z[i]'[t] ==  gamma[i] y[i][t] + delta[i - 1] z[i - 1][t] - delta[i] z[i][t]}, {i, 1, 10}], 
 Flatten[Table[{x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]}, {i, 1, 10}]], t]
```